# Could not able to access the kubernetes API after deleting the default-token

Tags: kubernetes

I am facing the issue when I delete the `default-token` secret of service account.

Kubernetes automatically mounts the `deafult-token` into the pod spec so that you can access its API.

```
volumes:
- name: default-token-hh98h
  secret:
    defaultMode: 420
    secretName: default-token-xxx
```

Now when I delete the secret `default-token-xxx`, kubernetes automatically creates new `default-token-yyy`, but that token doesn't reflect in the pod spec. If I restart the pods then the new token takes effect.

Is there any way to refresh the `default-token` secret without deleting the pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to update `secretName` field of `pod.spec.volume` because it is forbidden.
Even when you try to change, you will get an error

```
* spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

And you are trying to update `spec.volumes` which is forbidden